# Is this function a pmf?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

I have the following function, which seems to be a pmf, but I could not prove it (i.e. the sum over all possible outcomes is 1):

$$
f(k) =\frac{ {{n-p}\choose{p-k}} {{p}\choose {k}}} { {{n}\choose{p}} }
$$
You can assume that $n \ge 2p$, which means that all possible values of $k=0,1,\dots, p$ make sense.

**Shortly**:

> I want to prove that $\sum \limits_{k=0}^p f(k) = 1$

Some details: it should represent the probability to get $k$ common element from two combination. In other words, fixed a combination of $p$ element over $n$ (look at the denominator. it consider all the possible combinations), $f(k)$ should represent the probability that another combination has exactly $k$ elements in common with the previous one (the second factor of the numerator represents the number of ways to get $k$ element from the set of $p$ choosen elements in the fixed combination, namely $p$, while the first factor counts the ways to pick the other $p-k$ elements from the not-choosen elements of the fixed combination, namely $n-p$).

Comment: How do you think to apply it in this case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a bag of $n$ balls. $p$ of them are red, and $n-p$ of them are green. You randomly pick $p$ balls out of the bag. Your function $f(k)$ is the probability that $k$ of the balls you have picked out are red.

From this description, it's obvious that $f(k)$ is a probability distribution - there is no need to do any algebra!

Comment: Ok, but what I needed is a formal proof, for which @NCh gives me a good advice.

Comment: Sure. I like @NCh's comment too. Still, there is no reason why we can't turn this intuition about probability into a formal proof!

Comment: This IS a formal proof (or at least it's only a few steps away from one).